# No input file specified в PhpStorm?

Tags: php, html

Использую phpStorm, обычный html код и в нем кусочек php кода, но при открытии в браузере выдает no input file specified
В чем может быть проблема?

```
<div class="main cf">

    <?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
    <div class="header cf">
```

Comment: логи apache, php или nginx смотрели?

Comment: Не знаю, что это

Comment: Просто выбрал путь к пхп в вебшторме)